# How can I use Perl default array variable @_ with push?

Tags: perl

In the [perlvar documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) there is a text about `@_`:

> Within a subroutine the array @_ contains the parameters passed to
>   that subroutine. Inside a subroutine, @_ is the default array for the
>   array operators push, pop, shift, and unshift.

It is a common way to use `shift` without parameters to get first element from the array. It is very often used as:

```
sub some_method {
    my $self = shift; # the same as `my $self = shift @_;`

    ...
}
```

But in the documentation there is written that it can be used with `push`, but I can't create working example without explicitly specifying `@_` to the push. From reading this doc I'm expecting `push 123;` to push to `@_`, but it is not working.

Comment: I've used perbug and send a messge. Here is that I have send — https://gist.github.com/bessarabov/2e938f4bbb79e78d1941

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you've found an error in the documentation.

`@_` is the default for `pop` and `shift`, but not for `push` and `unshift`. For both `push` and `unshift`, the array has to be specified explicitly.

`perldoc -f push` shows the syntax as:

```
push ARRAY,LIST
push EXPR,LIST
```

with no option to leave the array unspecified; likewise for `perldoc -f unshift`.

(The OP has submitted a Perl bug report; see https://gist.github.com/bessarabov/2e938f4bbb79e78d1941)

**UPDATE:**

This has been corrected. In the git repo for Perl, it was corrected in commit `256ca3d37ed232e10fbb2884be45691e745be7a9`, 2015-06-21. The fix appears in releases 5.23.1 and 5.24.0. This doesn't seem to be mentioned in any of the `perldelta*.pod` files.